# "Relax! = be careful!"?

Tags: verbs

I watched a movie last night and one of the scene was about *a man pulling out the other man through the car window forcibly*.
Then, the man that was being pulled out started screaming,

> **Hey, relax. ow, ow, ow**.

What does ***relax*** mean in that condition? Is it like a command to ask somebody to **Be careful**?

Comment: ***Relax**!* in such contexts means ***Calm down! Don't panic!*** Presumably the "rescuer" was roughly manhandling the "victim", ***and it hurt***. But be honest - would you be wondering what he meant if the man had shouted ***Take it easy, willya!***

Comment: So it could be "be careful while pulling me out", isn't it?

Ya, i would. What does it mean?

Comment: It means ***Don't panic** [because in your panicky state, you're manhandling me, and it hurts]*. You can tell yourself ***relax*** means ***be careful*** in this exact context if you like, but I don't think that's a useful way of looking at. After all, the guy in the car might just as easily have shouted ***Watch it!*** or ***Hold on there!*** He just wants the other guy to realise how delicate the situation is.

Comment: Ease up, man! You are hurting me (by pulling me out carelessly)

Answer (score 1):

The person was seriously injured, that's why he said relax. So that there would not any further pain or injury. That means the speaker was trying to express " be clam no need to be hurried ".

Is that make you clear? Rey